# C++, Ifstream opens local file but not file on HTTP Server

Tags: c++

I am using ifstream to open a file and then read from it.
My program works fine when i give location of the local file 
on my system. 
for eg 
/root/Desktop/abc.xxx  works fine

But once the location is on the http server the file fails to
open.
for eg
http://192.168.0.10/abc.xxx fails to open.

Is there any alternate for ifstream when using a URL address?

thanks.

Comment: Yes. But it is not that simple. The server has to be able to processes the request. So the question is what is running on 192.168.0.10 to processes the request? Are you running a web server or file shearing server or some other thing that shares files from your server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no utilities in the standard C++ library for accessing data via http protocol.

There are 3rd-party libraries though:
[Libwww](http://www.w3.org/Library/) 
[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Another option is to have a virtual filesystem that maps remote http files as local files. This way you don't have to modify your application to access http. Something like http://okmij.org/ftp/HTTP-VFS.html

Answer (score 3):

ifstream will not read files off of an HTTP Server. It will only read local files.

Comment: More precisely, it reads local filesystems, files may reside elsewhere like in NFS case.

Comment: @Maxim, yes true. I believe Windows or Linux or some OS had an option for even mapping HTTP and FTP into the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

The `f` in [`ifstream`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) is for `file`, not `socket`.

You need to make an [HTTP GET Request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) and then stream the response, this is a totally different operation.

Consider using [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/), or similar. [[Examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)]

**Update**

Since the web server is on your local area network (judging by the IP address - not sure why people still insist in using those in these heady days of DNS, but that's by the by), you could probably mount the filesystem containing the desired file on your local machine, using NFS or similar. Then you'd be able to perform *file* operations, such a reading with ifstream.

Answer (score 0):

ifstream only works with files accessible on the filesystem, not on web servers.

Comment: any alternate to ifstream when using web addresses?

Comment: You need to perform socket communication to the Web Server and then provide the HTTP response in the form of a stream (if you need it in that form).